# How to return confirm on close button click in fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to alert confirmation message on button click in fancybox i am editing

```
closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
```

this portion of code in fancybox.js like

```
closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" onClick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"></a>',
```

This is showing confiration dialog but both on yes/no it returns true.Fancybox is closing.

Comment: see your Close btn is triggering event to close fancybox, so it won't wait for confirm response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply do it by using : beforeClosing method:

```
$(".fancyTrigger").fancybox(
       {
        'beforeClose' : function() {
        return window.confirm('Close?');
       }
  });
```

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/826/

For more Info:

check our http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ documentation section.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this..
`closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" onClick="return makesure();"></a>',`

Give a function outside

```
function makesure(){return confirm('Are you sure?');}
```

Answer (score -1):

i made it myself
i changed some code in fancybox.js

```
if (current.closeBtn) {
                $(current.tpl.closeBtn).appendTo(F.skin).bind('click.fb', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    F.close();
                });
            }
```

to

```
if (current.closeBtn) {
                $(current.tpl.closeBtn).appendTo(F.skin).bind('click.fb', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
                         F.close();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Go with predefined methods, it will be good to use existing methods, instead of re-inventing it